# How to declare defaultProps for the nested object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

In react component there is nested object in `propTypes` which works fine.

```
UserCard.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string,
  customer: PropTypes.shape({
    email: PropTypes.string,
    phoneNumber: PropTypes.string,
  }),
};
```

Looking for solution to assign `defaultProps` for the nested objects. It seems to be current implementation is not valid solution.

```
UserCard.defaultProps = {
  name: 'No Name',
  email: 'No Email',
  phoneNumber: '0',
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
UserCard.defaultProps = {
  name: 'No name',
  customer: {
      email: 'No email',
      phoneNumber: '0',
  },
};
```